Flutter , stream letters to a single sentence
I'm getting a stream of words from server. The objective is to combine the words into a single sentence dynamically. Now what happens is as follows, the values are appended, but the entire string is duplicated whenever a new letter is added.
eg: hi , how are you ?  // stream of words or letters



Expected : hi, how are you?

what im getting is as follows
hi
hi,
hi, how
hi, how are
hi, how are you
hi, how are you ?

My objective is dynamically add this to a string so i can pass that to the ui to render
StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
String newPart = '';

subscription = _channel.stream.listen(
    (message) {
      final actualMessage = message['message']; // from where i get data or values
      if (actualMessage != 'END') {
        newPart += actualMessage;
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.write(newPart);
        debugPrint(buffer.toString().trim());
        add(UiEvent.response(
            message: buffer.toString().trim()));
      }
    },
    onError: (error) {
      debugPrint("stream Error $error");
    },
  );

i need to dynamically append data and send it to ui. what am i missing? how can i implement this correctly?

I suppose the following piece of code is responsible for displaying the text on the UI:
add(UiEvent.response(message: buffer.toString().trim()));

And 'END' as message signals the end of the string.
Then changing your code to the following solution should work for you.
String messageToDisplay = '';

subscription = _channel.stream.listen(
  (message) {
      final actualMessage = message['message']; // from where i get data or values
      if (actualMessage != 'END') {
          messageToDisplay += ' $actualMessage';
      } else {
          // debug
          debugPrint(messageToDisplay.trim());
          // display messageToDisplay in ui
          add(UiEvent.response(message: messageToDisplay.trim()));
          // then clear messageToDisplay to make 
          // it ready for the next set of strings
          messageToDisplay = '';
      }
},
  onError: (error) {
    debugPrint("stream Error $error");
  },
);

For dynamically adding every words from stream, you can amend the code to this:
  if (actualMessage == 'END') {
      // send new line to ui to signal end of sentence
      add(UiEvent.response(message: '\n'));
  } else {
      // debug
      debugPrint(messageToDisplay.trim());
      // display the last message from stream
      add(UiEvent.response(message: actualMessage.trim()));
  }

Note: For the last solution to work, you need to make sure the code
add(UiEvent....

only displays new line if it receives the newline as message

in this scenario, only after completing appending full words into string im passing the value. Some cases there might be huge chunk of data. is there anyway that i can dynamically add this? because if the value say is above 200 words, there will be a load time right?  is there any way i can do that?

previously waited for the messages to complete. but since the response is taking time i want to make it dynamically add every words from stream without the issue.

@FebinJohnson I have added the dynamic part, hopefully it can give you some ideas.
